# fixed-data-table Как добавить строку в конец сформированной таблицы?

Tags: reactjs

fixed-data-table нужно в конец таблицы добавить строку, с суммой столбцов например.
Не могу найти в доке каким образом можно это сделать, подскажите кто сталкивлся. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

У элемента column указать атрибут footer
У таблицы обязательно указать высоту футера footerHeight, без него футер не отрисуется